# Failure in locating ValueCombiner in MvvmCross Android project

Tags: data-binding, mono, xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I'm trying to use Tibet binding alongside a value combiner, I couldn't get it to work in my custom implementation, I kept on getting this error:

`12-22 16:59:27.617 I/MvxBind (12700):   3.77 Failed to find combiner or converter for Counting`

so I copy pasted the example from the [Wiki](https://github.com/rafaelsteil/MvvmCross-Wiki/blob/master/Value-Converters.md):

```
public class CountingValueCombiner
: MvxValueCombiner
{
    public CountingValueCombiner()
    {
        Android.Util.Log.Error("!!!", "In combiner");
    }
    public override Type SourceType(IEnumerable<IMvxSourceStep> steps)
    {
        return typeof(int);
    }

    public override System.Boolean TryGetValue(IEnumerable<IMvxSourceStep> steps, out Object value)
    {
        var count = 0;
        foreach (var input in steps)
        {
            object innerResult = input;


            if (innerResult != null)
                count++;
        }

        value = count;
        return true;
    }
}
```

And in the xml:

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#ff00ff"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        local:MvxBind="Text Counting(FirstName, Title)"/>
```

where FirstName and Title are string properties for the ViewModel.
The class is on the droid project, however the locator does not seem to find the combiner no matter what.
After looking in the source code I found that the registration code is in `MvxCoreBindingBuilder` and it's invoked on `protected virtual void FillValueCombiners(IMvxValueCombinerRegistry registry)`

I could not find out how to manually register, as I'm getting a binding error:
`12-22 16:59:27.617 I/MvxBind (12700):   3.77 Failed to find combiner or converter for Counting`

Any ideas how to get around this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because value combiners are much less frequently used than value converters, mvx doesn't search for them in app assemblies by default.

The good news is that it's relatively easy yo search for them yourself - or to register them manually. To do this, look for the value converters callback in setup - in https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/3.2/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Droid/Platform/MvxAndroidSetup.cs - you can override the callback block in your code to add your own hook for the value combiner registry.

Sorry this answer is a little vague - its hard to talk tech on a 3" touch screen. Can add more detail in a week...

Comment: @slodge thanks for the quick response! That definitely did the trick, I overrided `FillValueConverters(IMvxValueConverterRegistry registry)` in the Setup file and registered to the `Mvx.CallbackWhenRegistered<IMvxValueCombinerRegistry>` callback, the registration did the trick.. I don't think there's any screen size that could stop you, many thanks!

Comment: that's why it's bad to post link answers - link is not valid anymore